# Proof-verification: $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus T$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

The following question is from Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*:

> Let $S$ be an open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $T$ be a
>   component of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n
>  \setminus T$ is connected.

I am not able to complete my proof:

> For all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (S \cup T),$denote $U(x)$ as the
>   component containing $x$. Now we claim that for every $x \in
>  \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (S \cup T),U(x) \cap \bar{S} \neq \phi$. If so,
>   then there exists $k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $k \in U(x) \cap
>  \bar{S}$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}^n \setminus T \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be a
>   2-valued function. There exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset S$ such
>   that it converges to $k$. Note that $S$ is connect, then $f$ is
>   constant on $S$, say $f(S) \equiv 0$. Since $f$ is continuous,
>   $f(k)=0$. Since $U(x)$ is connected, $f(U(x))=0$. Repeat the same
>   argument for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus T$ and we are done.

1. Is my proof valid?
2. How can I prove my claim that $U(x) \cap \bar{S} \neq \phi$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof seems fine, except for the missing claim.

To prove the claim, note that $U = U(x)$ is closed since it is a connected component of the closed set $\mathbb{R}^n - S$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, $U$ cannot also be open. Therefore $U$ has some boundary point $a$. If we had $a \not\in \overline{S}$, then there would be some ball $B$ centred at $a$ and not meeting $S$. But then $U \cup B$ would be a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n - S$ properly containing $U$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am wondering that if we change $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a general metric space, can we still use the same argument to make such a conclusion. One thing I notice is that in a general metric space, an open ball $B$ may be not connected, thus we may not reach the contradiction as above. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the argument would need to be made in a connected, locally connected space.